# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0.. parse file incorrect?

Tags: java, android, arrays, parsing

I am trying to make an android application that parses pictures from online in a grid/list however Im coming up with some runtime errors.. its saying that i am parsing wrong for my FAMILY DOG BREED. Does anyone know where I am making my errors?? I know why an array would be out of bounds but i have no idea how to fix it!!

I am trying to parse http://www.dogbreedslist.info/family-dog-breeds/ this website data.. but am getting runtime errors at these sections of my

DogActivity.class

```
  private class RetrieveDogsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
           for (String url : urls) {
            Parser parser = new Parser(url, DogsActivity.this);
            Breed.Name breedName = breed.getName();
            if (breedName == Breed.Name.HERDING_DOG_BREED) {
                dogs.add(parser.parseProfile(new Dog(url, breedName)));
            } else {
                dogs.addAll(parser.parseDogsPage(breedName,    DogsActivity.this));
            }
          }
        return null;
    }
```

Parser.class

```
public class Parser {
Document doc;
Context context;
Elements dogRows;

public Parser(String url, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Page", "Wrong URL or network problems", e);
    }

}

public ArrayList<Dog> parseDogsPage(Breed.Name breedName, Context context) {
    ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Element dogContainer;
        if (breedName == Breed.Name.FAMILY_DOG_BREED) {
            dogContainer = doc.getElementsByClass("familybreed").get(0);
        } else {
            dogContainer = doc.getElementsByClass("toybreed").get(0);
        }
        Log.i("Page", "A page has been parsed successfully");
        dogRows = dogContainer.getElementsByTag("a");
        for (Element dogRow : dogRows) {
            String dogName, dogURL;
            Dog dog;
            dogURL = dogRow.getElementsByTag("a").get(0).absUrl("href");
            String dogThumbnailURL = dogRow.
                    getElementsByTag("img").get(0).absUrl("src");
            if (breedName == Breed.Name.FAMILY_DOG_BREED) {
                dogName = dogRow.getElementsByTag("span").get(0).text();
                dog = new Dog(dogName, dogURL, dogThumbnailURL, breedName);
            } else {
                dogName = dogRow.getElementsByTag("strong").get(0).text();
                Element details = dogContainer.getElementsByClass("details").get(0);
                Elements children = details.children();
                if (breedName == Breed.Name.TOY_DOG_BREED || breedName == Breed.Name.HOUND_DOG_BREED) {
                    String origin = children.get(1).text();
                    String lifespan = children.get(3).text();
                    dog= new Dog(dogName, origin , lifespan, dogURL, dogThumbnailURL, breedName);
                } else {
                    //for herding
                    String sizetype = children.get(1).text();
                    dog = new Dog(dogName, sizetype, dogThumbnailURL, dogURL, breedName);
                }
            }

            dogs.add(dog);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Breed activity", "Wrong parsing for " + breedName, e);
    }
    return dogs;
}


public Dog parseProfile(Dog dog) {
    if (!dog.isDetailDataReady()) {
        //coaches already read the data in the coaches page
        try {
            Element dogContainer = doc.getElementById("dogscontainer");
            Element bioContainer = dogContainer.getElementById("biocontainer");
            Element bioDetails = bioContainer.getElementById("biodetails");
            dog.setOtherNames(bioDetails.getElementsByTag("h1").text());

            ArrayList<Dog.Detail> dogDetails = new ArrayList<>();
            Elements rows = bioDetails.getElementsByTag("tr");
            for (Element row : rows) {
                Elements tds = row.getElementsByTag("td");
                if (dog.getBreed() == Breed.Name.WORKING_DOG_BREED ||
                        dog.getBreed() == Breed.Name.TERRIER_DOG_BREED ||
                        dog.getBreed() == Breed.Name.HERDING_DOG_BREED) {
                    //coaches, manager and legends use th and td
                    Elements ths = row.getElementsByTag("th");
                    dogDetails.add(new Dog.Detail(ths.get(0).text(), tds.get(0).text()));
                } else {
                    //dogs use two tds
                    dogDetails.add(new Dog.Detail(tds.get(0).text(), tds.get(1).text()));
                }
            }
            dog.setDetails(dogDetails);

            Element articleText = dogContainer.getElementsByClass("dogarticletext").get(0);
            Elements paragraphs = articleText.getElementsByTag("p");
            String text = "";
            for (Element p : paragraphs) {
                text = text + "\n\n\n" + p.text();
            }
            dog.setArticleText(dog.getArticleText() + text);

            if (dog.getBreed() == Breed.Name.WORKING_DOG_BREED ||
                    dog.getBreed() == Breed.Name.TERRIER_DOG_BREED ||
                    dog.getBreed() == Breed.Name.HERDING_DOG_BREED) {

                //get main image url
                dog.setMainImageURL(bioContainer.getElementsByTag("img").get(0).absUrl("src"));
                if (dog.getBreed() == Breed.Name.WORKING_DOG_BREED) {
                    dog.setThumbnailURL(dog.getMainImageURL());
                    //only need first name
                    dog.setName(dog.getOtherNames().split(" ")[1]);
                }
            } else {
                dog.setMainImageURL(bioContainer.getElementsByClass("mainImage").get(0).absUrl("src"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Profile activity", "Wrong parsing for " + dog.getUrl(), e);
        }
        if (dog.getBreed() == Breed.Name.WORKING_DOG_BREED) {
            dog.setBasicDataReady(true);
        }
        dog.setDetailDataReady(true);
    }
    return dog;
}
```

}

RetrieveDogTask:

```
 private class RetrieveDogsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        for (String url : urls) {
            Parser parser = new Parser(url, DogsActivity.this);
            Breed.Name breedName = breed.getName();
            if (breedName == Breed.Name.HERDING_DOG_BREED) {
                dogs.add(parser.parseProfile(new Dog(url, breedName)));
            } else {
                dogs.addAll(parser.parseDogsPage(breedName, DogsActivity.this));
            }
        }

        return null;
```

Logcat:

```
 Wrong parsing for FAMILY_DOG_BREED
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
  at org.jsoup.select.Elements.get(Elements.java:544)
  at com.example.shannon.popular.Parser.parseDogsPage(Parser.java:35)
           at            com.example.shannon.popular.DogsActivity$RetrieveDogsTask.doInBackground(DogsActivity.java:140)  
      at com.example.shannon.popular.DogsActivity$RetrieveDogsTask.doInBackground(DogsActivity.java:131)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Breed.class:

```
public class Breed implements Serializable {
private Name name;
private String url;


Breed(Name name, String url) {
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url;
}

public Name getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getNameString(Context context) {
    String nameString = "";
    switch (name) {
        case FAMILY_DOG_BREED:
            nameString = context.getString(R.string.family_breed);
            break;
        case TOY_DOG_BREED:
            nameString = context.getString(R.string.toy_breed);
            break;
        case HOUND_DOG_BREED:
            nameString = context.getString(R.string.hound_breed);
            break;
        case TERRIER_DOG_BREED:
            nameString = context.getString(R.string.terrier_breed);
            break;
        case WORKING_DOG_BREED:
            nameString = context.getString(R.string.working_breed);
            break;
        case HERDING_DOG_BREED:
            nameString = context.getString(R.string.herding_breed);
            break;
    }
    return nameString;
}

public String getURL() {
    return url;
}

public enum Name {FAMILY_DOG_BREED, TOY_DOG_BREED, HOUND_DOG_BREED, TERRIER_DOG_BREED, WORKING_DOG_BREED, HERDING_DOG_BREED}
```

}

Comment: Please add the complete logcat report to the question

Comment: I edited the question to include the logcat

Comment: can you please explain what is Breed.Name? where Name is the inner class in Breed?

Comment: I have a Breed class where a number of dog breeds are listed in a switch statement and then I have a BreedActivity where I have  breeds = new ArrayList<Breed>() {{
            add(new Breed(Breed.Name.FAMILY_DOG_BREED,
                      "http://www.dogbreedslist.info/family-dog-breeds/"));
            add(new Breed(Breed.Name.HOUND_DOG_BREED,
                    "http://www.dogbreedslist.info/hound-dog-breeds/"));
            add(new Breed(Breed.Name.TOY_DOG_BREED,
                    "http://www.dogbreedslist.info/toy-dog-breeds/"));

Comment: can you please add the Breed class to the question

Comment: Yes I have just included it

Comment: @ShadowDroid i added the breed class :)

Comment: thank you for including requested things... in the logcat report console you can click on link at com.example.shannon.popular.Parser.parseDogsPage(Parser.java:35) it will take you to line which is throwing exception... in the method parseDogsPage...also check the document properly whether all the elements are in multiple and do you need get(0) with each element.Since you have used get(0) at many place right now I cannot pinpoint the exact line...

Comment: If you are still not able to fix it...either add the Document doc object to the question or the html which you are parsing...

Comment: @ShadowDroid i added the doc i am trying to parse its a dog website - and also the part thats throwing an error on my DogActivity.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using a strict XML parser for a malformed HTML document. I just tried to XML-validate the URL you are parsing and it's failing because the `<link>` element is never closed (in strict XML, it should be ended by a `</link>` tag, but it's missing in that page). 
This is very common for HTML pages as today's browsers tend to auto-correct these kinds of errors.

Since you use a strict XML parser, it is very likely for the parser to fail.

I suggest switching to  different parser. I'd use a PULL parser (eg. http://www.xmlpull.org ) - this technique allows parsing with a lower-level of control, meaning you can easily ignore unwanted content from the HTML - like these link elements, or any others.

So you could do something like this:

```
XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();

parser.setInput(new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                        new URL("http://.....").openConnection().getInputStream()
                    )
                )
            );

while(XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT != parser.next()){
    if(XmlPullParser.START_TAG == parser.getEventType()){
        String tagName = parser.getName();
        if(parser.getAttributeCount() > 0 {
             // parse attributes, if needed
        }
        if(parser.nextToken() == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
             String tagValue = parser.getText()
        }
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will give this a go and let you know how it goes!!

Comment: Please let me know if you need more info on this track. Good luck!